# Very Basic question on Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a class like this -

```
public class MyClass : ISomeInterface
{
        public MyClass(string connString)
        {
            // set conn string on a private member
        }


       // interface methods
       public CreateDb(string dbName) {...}

       public DropDb(string dbName) {...}

       public string GetLastError() {...}
}
```

It is part of a legacy code and I have to write UnitTests. Now, if I want to write tests just for this class, how do I proceed such that I cover all public methods with 100% test coverage ?
Can anyone provide a small sample w.r.t the class ?

**EDIT** - The CreateDb and DropDb catch SqlException and sets error message. Error Message is exposed via a public interface method GetlastError()

NOTE: I am using RhinoMocks & MSTest

Comment: you need to provide more info about the contents of CreateDb and DropDb methods, specifically in regards to the class' dependencies.

Comment: 100% statement, branch or path coverage? you can't ever measure you're test coverage only your execution coverage. Just because code is executed during test doesn't mean it's tested

Comment: The createDb and DropDb catch SqlException and sets error message. Error Message is exposed via a public interface method GetlastError()

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods in the class.

You have to write unit test for three methods.

For

```
public <Returntype> MyClass(string ConString)
{

}
```

There should atleast two unit test.

1) What your code does when ConString is Null or Empty. If it is null or empty then you have to catch the Exception

2) When Connection string is correct, What is last statement or confirmation you will be displaying.

More info on RhinoMocks  [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Rhino_Mocks.aspx)

Comment: The createDb and DropDb catch SqlException and sets error message. Error Message is exposed via a public interface method GetlastError()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class creates some real DB, you'd have two options testing this class:

> 1. Let the class create and release the real DB, and have the tests assert that the DB is created as expected.
> 2. Use a DB [Mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), and have the tests assert that the calls to the mock were correct. If you want to use this option, you'd have, again, to choose:
>
> > a. Don't change your code and use Mocking Framework which supports method call interecption such as [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/quick-start-page-core/).
> >     b. Change your code to have a c'tor or property which takes interface of the DB (AkA [Dependancy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)), and use RhinoMocks to mock the DB interface.

Hope it helps, and maybe you could provide more details to the question, so the answer could be more detailed :-)